# Why doesn't YouTube center ads?

Tags: gui-design, layout

Left aligned
[image: Youtube ad left aligned]

Centered ad
[image: Youtube ad centered]

Is there any reason why Youtube is not centering the ads? It is very simple to center it, so I am guessing they are thinking about some user experience.

Comment: It is easier for the viewer's eye to just skip the ad by not aligning it with the video suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Centering the ad would break the grid layout

- The YouTube interface is dense with hierarchical information (main video, info panel, comment panel, suggestions panel, multiple nav bars, etc.)
- To organize this complex information, YouTube uses a [grid layout](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/grid-theory-41411345) pattern to provide clear lines and rectangles of organization.  Grid layout are proven to help organize complex interfaces and calm the user experience.
- Vertical and horizontal alignment of elements to gridlines is a crucial aspect of grid layouts. "Grid-breaking" elements which are not aligned tend to stand out. Designers sometimes use grid-breaking placement when they want to highlight something, but it needs to be used sparingly and intentionally to avoid the feeling clutter and disorganization.

Centering the YouTube ad does exactly that. It draws the eye towards the ad because it breaks grid alignment, which is not something YouTube wants to do (it may have design intent to keep the user focused on the main video panel, without being too intrusive with a grid breaking ad on the right)